# How to move tables from one schema to another schema in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I Have 2 schema in Oracle 19C with name `MyCon` and `sahe`. In `MyCon` schema I have many tables but  In `sahe` schema I don't have any table as shown as below.
[image]

I want move table with name `test` from `MyCon` schema to `sahe` schema. How can I do?

I run  `select * from all_tables order by table_name` and I get bellow result about (TableSpaceName, owner).
[image]

Note:  `sahe` schema have all PRIVILEGES .(`GRANT all PRIVILEGES  TO sahe;`)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use utility designed for such a purpose: **data pump**.

Here's an example. User `scott` owns some objects; I'll export it and import it into a new user, `mike`.

Connect as `SYS` and create a directory (Oracle object that points to a filesystem directory that contains dump files (or any other kind of files)); grant privileges to user(s) who will be using it. Why do we do that? Because data pump requires the directory.

```
SQL> create directory ext_dir as 'c:\temp';

Directory created.

SQL> grant read, write on directory ext_dir to scott;

Grant succeeded.
   
SQL>
```

---

Now, export `scott`:

```
c:\temp>expdp scott/tiger@pdb1 directory=ext_dir dumpfile=scott.dmp logfile=exp_scott.log

Export: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Jul 25 22:59:37 2022
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Starting "SCOTT"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01":  scott/********@pdb1 directory=ext_dir dumpfile=scott.dmp logfile=exp_scott.log
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/STATISTICS/MARKER
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PRE_SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/COMMENT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/FUNCTION/FUNCTION
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PROCEDURE/PROCEDURE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/FUNCTION/ALTER_FUNCTION
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PROCEDURE/ALTER_PROCEDURE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/REF_CONSTRAINT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TRIGGER
. . exported "SCOTT"."ORAERR"                            2.976 MB   59904 rows
. . exported "SCOTT"."ERRORS"                            12.09 KB     110 rows
. . exported "SCOTT"."EMP"                               8.789 KB      14 rows
. . exported "SCOTT"."SALESMEN"                          6.546 KB       6 rows
. . exported "SCOTT"."INVOICE"                           6.445 KB       4 rows
. . exported "SCOTT"."TESTS"                               6.5 KB       3 rows
. . exported "SCOTT"."DEPT"                              6.023 KB       4 rows
. . exported "SCOTT"."SALGRADE"                          5.953 KB       5 rows
. . exported "SCOTT"."DEPARTMENTS"                       5.945 KB       1 rows
. . exported "SCOTT"."PERSON"                            5.492 KB       1 rows
. . exported "SCOTT"."ACTIVE_YEAR"                       5.062 KB       1 rows
. . exported "SCOTT"."COPY_DEPARTMENTS"                  5.078 KB       1 rows
. . exported "SCOTT"."FOO"                               5.046 KB       1 rows
. . exported "SCOTT"."BONUS"                                 0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SCOTT"."DAT"                                   0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SCOTT"."DEPT_BACKUP"                       6.031 KB       4 rows
. . exported "SCOTT"."PROGRAMMER"                            0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SCOTT"."PROGRAMS"                              0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SCOTT"."REGIONS"                               0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SCOTT"."TBL_HISTORY"                           0 KB       0 rows
Master table "SCOTT"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
******************************************************************************
Dump file set for SCOTT.SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01 is:
  C:\TEMP\SCOTT.DMP
Job "SCOTT"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully completed at Mon Jul 25 23:00:27 2022 elapsed 0 00:00:48


c:\temp>
```

The next step is to import scott's schema into `mike`. Note that I didn't pre-create user `mike`, import data pump did it automatically.

```
c:\temp>impdp system@pdb1 directory=ext_dir dumpfile=scott.dmp logfile=imp_mike.log remap_schema=scott:mike full=y

Import: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Jul 25 23:21:40 2022
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
Password:

Connected to: Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Master table "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
Starting "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01":  system/********@pdb1 directory=ext_dir dumpfile=scott.dmp logfile=imp_mike.log remap_schema=scott:mike full=y
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/USER
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SYSTEM_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/ROLE_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/DEFAULT_ROLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/ON_USER_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLESPACE_QUOTA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PRE_SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
. . imported "MIKE"."ORAERR"                             2.976 MB   59904 rows
. . imported "MIKE"."ERRORS"                             12.09 KB     110 rows
. . imported "MIKE"."EMP"                                8.789 KB      14 rows
. . imported "MIKE"."SALESMEN"                           6.546 KB       6 rows
. . imported "MIKE"."INVOICE"                            6.445 KB       4 rows
. . imported "MIKE"."TESTS"                                6.5 KB       3 rows
. . imported "MIKE"."DEPT"                               6.023 KB       4 rows
. . imported "MIKE"."SALGRADE"                           5.953 KB       5 rows
. . imported "MIKE"."DEPARTMENTS"                        5.945 KB       1 rows
. . imported "MIKE"."PERSON"                             5.492 KB       1 rows
. . imported "MIKE"."ACTIVE_YEAR"                        5.062 KB       1 rows
. . imported "MIKE"."COPY_DEPARTMENTS"                   5.078 KB       1 rows
. . imported "MIKE"."FOO"                                5.046 KB       1 rows
. . imported "MIKE"."BONUS"                                  0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "MIKE"."DAT"                                    0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "MIKE"."DEPT_BACKUP"                        6.031 KB       4 rows
. . imported "MIKE"."PROGRAMMER"                             0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "MIKE"."PROGRAMS"                               0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "MIKE"."REGIONS"                                0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "MIKE"."TBL_HISTORY"                            0 KB       0 rows
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/FUNCTION/FUNCTION
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PROCEDURE/PROCEDURE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/FUNCTION/ALTER_FUNCTION
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PROCEDURE/ALTER_PROCEDURE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/REF_CONSTRAINT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TRIGGER
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/STATISTICS/MARKER
Job "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully completed at Mon Jul 25 23:21:53 2022 elapsed 0 00:00:08


c:\temp>
```

Finally, let's check what we've done (new user *inherited* scott's password):

```
c:\temp>sqlplus mike/tiger@pdb1

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Jul 25 23:23:50 2022
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0

SQL> show user
USER is "MIKE"
SQL> select count(*) from tab;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        20

SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

That's it; way simpler and more efficient that doing it manually, table-by-table, writing your own PL/SQL programs and stuff.

Comment: I want move just table with name `test` not all tables on `MyCon` schema. Can I use  this solution ?

Comment: I get this Error:`UDE-12154: operation generated ORACLE error 12154
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`

Comment: Yes, you can use data pump for a single table as well. See documentation for more info. As of ORA-12154, it looks as if TNSNAMES.ORA file doesn't contain alias to the database you used while providing login credentials.

Answer (score 0):

A table cannot be "moved" between schemas. You need to copy the table content, then drop the original, like this:

```
create table user_b.test
as
select * from user_a.test;

drop table user_a.test;
```

Note that you may want to specify additional parameters in your `create table` command, and you should not drop the original table until you've confirmed you have all the data in the new table.

Comment: In addition,  you may want to copy over the Grant's on the table too. You can use this or some variation that fits your needs. 
SELECT LISTAGG (
'GRANT '
|| PRIVILEGE
|| ' ON '
|| :TARGET_TABLE_OWNER
|| '.'
|| :TARGET_TABLE_NAME
|| ' TO '
|| GRANTEE,
'; ' || CHR (10)) 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY GRANTEE, PRIVILEGE) || ';'
FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = :SOURCE_TABLE_NAME
  AND OWNER = :SOURCE_TABLE_OWER;